# An inequality with matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Suppose one is given a set of $k$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $A_1,..,A_k$ and two positive real numbers $\alpha, \beta$.

- When can there exist a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ s.t $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we have, 
  $$ - \beta y^\top M x \leq y^\top A_i x \leq  \alpha y^\top M x  , \forall i = 1,\ldots,k$$

?

And sometimes is such a $M$ easy to construct out of the $As$?

Comment: Can you provide some contexts/backgrounds and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ exists only when all the $A_i$s are zero matrices.

If some $A_i$ is nonzero, there will be some $x$ and $y$ such that $y^TA_ix\ne0$. But then the set of inequalities
\begin{cases}
-\beta y^\top Mx\leq y^\top A_ix\leq\alpha y^\top Mx,\\
-\beta (-y)^\top Mx\leq (-y)^\top A_ix\leq\alpha (-y)^\top Mx
\end{cases}
cannot be simultaneously satisfied.